# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in Server.JS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am working with Vuejs and Nuxt using SSR. I am getting the error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" @ server.js:5833:43.  What is odd about this is that server.js is standard vue file, which I've made no edits to.  I made some changes to the Nuxt store prior to the issue.  I am not sure where to begin looking to debug.

Comment: Add some code, or better yet, a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: server.js is a file that is compiled by Nuxt from your code so essentially it contains your Nuxt-related code. You'll have to add relevant parts of your code where you try to get the `name` property from some object to your question.